# hibernate not returning result(HQL)

Tags: hibernate

After running the HQL (from dvdrentals.film) it's not returning records from the mysql database. Rather it returned 0 rows updated; 0rows selected. I am using netbeans 8.1, Glassfish server 4.1.1 and Java EE 7 web. Please help.

Comment: My crystal ball says the error is at line 57. But it doesn't say which file unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the below prop in hibernateProperties in the configuration xml and see the hql query being fired

```
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
```

Comment: I already have <property name =“hibernate.show.sql“>true</property> in my hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Comment: Did you get the query that is being executed in the logs or in the console?